# AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'DictReader'

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, temporary-files

I'm creating a temporary CSV file:

```
for formname in formnamesFinal:
    csv = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w", prefix=formname+'_', suffix=".csv", dir = "/var/tmp/")
csv.write(....)
```

And I'm writing something in it. Now I want to read this file with DictReader:

```
content = csv.DictReader(csv, delimiter=';')
for contenthelp in content:
    contentlist.append(contenthelp)
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'DictReader'
```

I have to step through the temp CSV files, because I have huge datasets to get from a database for the following steps and it would take too much time to load the data over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
csv = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w", prefix=formname+'_', suffix=".csv", dir = "/var/tmp/")
```

This line overwrites your reference to the `csv` module. Try renaming it to something else.

```
my_csv = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w", prefix=formname+'_', suffix=".csv", dir = "/var/tmp/")
```

Now you should be able to access `csv` properly again.

Answer (score 3):

- Another cause for this error is there is a python script with a filename of `csv.py`.
- This hides the name of Python's built-in csv module.
- Resolve the issue by renaming the user created `csv.py` script file.

Comment: Well, that would explain things! Thanks!